# after some edittext input automatically disable keypad in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to popdown Keyboard after some text. i.e. after some condition fulfilled. how to do this in android.
i.e. if(characters of eT1==Characters of et2)
eT1 is already inputed, now in et2 inputing.

i have used:
eT2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String oldPass = eT1.getText().toString();      if(!oldPass.contentEquals(e2.getText().toString()))
                {
                View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
```

if (view != null) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

```
                }
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                            int count, int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

Comment: try doing this in `afterTextChanged`

Comment: i tried. problem is View.getWindowToken() is Showing error. with Correction to define a new udf.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

et1.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(view.getText().equals(et2.getText()) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```